# "Optimize Battery Charging" Option is Missing - MacOS Monterey

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, monterey

I do not see the "Optimize Battery Charging" option within System Preferences > Battery > Battery.  I am running the latest version of macOS Monterey 12.0.1 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). Where is this setting?  I see Apple mentioned at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212049 although they don't specify if it's only available with certain hardware.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this only available on Mac's with M1 chips (not Intel)?

Comment: I can't seem to find the official resource but I believe the option is only available on Macs that charge over USB-C

Comment: I was under the impression it was for both Intel and M1.  I did find this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094 which talked about "Battery Health Management" which might be related, but it just specifies that is is "on by default" with that OS or hardware... "Battery health management is on by default when you buy a new Mac notebook with macOS 10.15.5 or later, or after you upgrade to macOS 10.15.5 or later on a Mac notebook with Thunderbolt 3 ports."  I'm assuming it's related to the fact that I do not have thunderbolt 3 ports, but it's not fully clear if that's the case.

Comment: I can confirm that the option is available on an Intel MacBook Pro (2018, 15-inch). The requirement could either be having Thunderbolt 3 or the T2 chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the article linked below along with on my experience testing a Macbook Pro Late 2013, Mid 2015 and 2019 (all updated to as high a OS version as capable) I can confirm that the 2019 is the only one of the three machines I tested that has the Optimize Battery Charging feature.

The article [About battery health management in Mac notebooks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094) by Apple published November 17, 2020 states the following...

> Battery health management is on by default when you buy a new Mac notebook with macOS 10.15.5 or later, or after you upgrade to macOS 10.15.5 or later on a Mac notebook with Thunderbolt 3 ports.

So I'm assuming that it is the Thunderbolt 3 ports that are the key here since only the 2019 machine that I tested has them.  I'm also going under the assumption that "Optimize Battery Charging" is a feature of their "Battery Health Management" feature.  Although the documentation is not 100% clear on that point, I feel like it's a safe bet.

Comment: I can confirm that the option is available on an Intel MacBook Pro (2018, 15-inch). The requirement could either be having Thunderbolt 3 (introduced in the 2016 models) or the T2 chip (introduced in the 2018 models). You might want to consider rephrasing your answer, reading it suggests the 2019 being the only model with the option in general.